# How can I make a NumberLineLogPlot'?

Tags: piecewise, ticks, logarithmic-scale

I have a piecewise function that is defined in logarithmic intervals, i.e., the different pieces are defined on

```
{{1. <= x <= 10}, {10 <= x <= 100}, {100 <= x <= 1000}}
```

I'd like to visualize the different domains on a number line.
`NumberLinePlot`, of course, works, but it looks clumsy as the plot is fully dominated by the last domain an the first one is barely visible:

```
NumberLinePlot[{{1. <= x <= 10}, {10 <= x <= 100}, {100 <= x <= 1000}}, {x, 1, 1000}]
```

[image]

So I can use something along the lines of

```
NumberLinePlot[
  {{Log[10, 1] <= x <= Log[10, 10]}, 
   {Log[10, 10] <= x <= Log[10, 100]}, 
   {Log[10, 100] <= x <= Log[10, 1000]}}, 
  {x, Log[10, 1], Log[10, 1000]}]
```

which results in a much more pleasantly balanced plot:

[image]

However, now the number line ticks show the exponents — so in essence I'd like something like `NumberLineLogPlot`, but that doesn't exist.

I tried to recreate something like that by abusing `LogLogPlot`

```
Show[
  MapThread[
    LogLogPlot[#1, #2, PlotStyle -> #3] &, 
    {{1, 2, 4}, {x, #[[1, 1]], #[[1, 3]]} & /@ dx , {Red, Green, Blue}}], 
  PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}]
```

Which leads to something like

[image]

which is better in terms of the logarithmic x-axis but is quite clumsy in other ways.

Any ideas how to implement a `NumberLineLogPlot` nicely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the option [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)

```
intervals = {{1 <= x <= 10}, {10 <= x <= 100}, {100 <= x <= 1000}};

logIntervals = intervals /. {n_?NumericQ :> Log10[n]}

(* {{0 <= x <= 1}, {1 <= x <= 2}, {2 <= x <= 3}} *)

NumberLinePlot[logIntervals, {x, 0, 3}, 
 Ticks -> {({Log10[#], #} & /@ 
    {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000}), None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one! I particularly like the trick with the patternreplacement for the Log[]

Answer (score 1):

You can also transform `intervals` into a list of lists and use `ListLinePlot` with the option `ScalingFunctions`:

```
lst = MapIndexed[Thread[{#[[1]], #2[[1]]/2}] &, intervals /. LessEqual -> ({#, #3} &)]; 
Show[ListLinePlot[lst, ScalingFunctions -> {{Log[10, #] &, 10^# &}, None},
   Joined -> #] & /@ {True, False}, AspectRatio -> 1/5, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image]